# Get profile information retrieved from sign in users firebase null return

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework

From my firebase data I`m trying to access the users information like what government agency and displayname using [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users) example from firebase docs. When I use this example came f

```
    {
  "users" : {
    "citizen" : {
      "NiPS4VtdFPgVMVyhCVfMtzdP85g1" : {
        "displayName" : "user-citizen",
        "email" : "user@user.com",
        "password" : "palls123",
        "pnumber" : "123",
        "repassword" : "palls123"
      },
      "Pba7iULL4wYkTQxHB5tpbNDj7v02" : {
        "displayName" : "kevin",
        "email" : "ez@ez.com",
        "password" : "palls123",
        "pnumber" : "545",
        "repassword" : "palls123"
      },
      "gf2o8dhs9VhIsCK5Ui5rEizESbj1" : {
        "displayName" : "kevin",
        "email" : "dli@dli.com",
        "password" : "palls123",
        "pnumber" : "5454",
        "repassword" : "palls123"
      }
    },
    "government" : {
      "bfp" : {
        "AgIqgADtMeNS5d3BJTnCI0uCjcl1" : {
          "displayName" : "bfp-user",
          "email" : "bfp@bfp.com",
          "gov_agency" : "bfp",
          "gov_id" : "123",
          "password" : "palls123",
          "pnumber" : "1234",
          "repassword" : "palls123",
          "toggle" : true
        }
      },
      "ndrmmc" : {
        "XdoC2Dny5ZM69z8B2BrSWBS3CIY2" : {
          "displayName" : "ndrmmc-user",
          "email" : "ndrmmc@ndrmmc.com",
          "gov_agency" : "ndrmmc",
          "gov_id" : "123",
          "password" : "palls123",
          "pnumber" : "123",
          "repassword" : "palls123",
          "toggle" : true
        }
      },
      "pnp" : {
        "MhKiEoCtytQAHooHclSZIB3gsK42" : {
          "displayName" : "pnp-user",
          "email" : "pnp@pnp.com",
          "gov_agency" : "pnp",
          "gov_id" : "23455",
          "password" : "palls123",
          "pnumber" : "1234",
          "repassword" : "palls123",
          "toggle" : true
        }
      },
      "rta" : {
        "fehvPVwX6NXnVkf3hOyRsQBDH2Y2" : {
          "displayName" : "rta-user",
          "email" : "rta@rta.com",
          "gov_agency" : "rta",
          "gov_id" : "1234",
          "password" : "palls123",
          "pnumber" : "123",
          "repassword" : "palls123",
          "toggle" : true
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I`m trying to access the users information like what government agency and displayname using [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users) example from firebase docs. When I use this example came from the docs

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (user != null) {
  user.providerData.forEach(function (profile) {
    console.log(" Gov Agency : " + profile.gov_agency);
    console.log("  Provider-specific UID: " + profile.uid);
    console.log("  Name: " + profile.displayName);
  });
}
```

It returns null on my side except for the uid it gives email of the user. Where did I go wrong?

PS: There are two types of user a gov client and citizen client

Comment: from the json you have in the question it looks like you're referencing two different things, user and a document in your DB. I think you need to ref the DB doc `users`. Something like this `this.users = this.afs.collection('users').valueChanges();` depending on the DB you have set up, above is for firestore.

Comment: so the thing here is when I login , i must get the users info from the time it logs in to determine if it is a gov client or a citizen client. from the answer you said i cant really image how would do that @alphapilgrim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normal that you get a null value for `profile.gov_agency`: as detailed [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#providerData), the `providerData` property of a [User](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User) is a "non-null Array of `firebase.UserInfo`"

In turns, a [UserInfo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.UserInfo) has a set of **defined** properties: `email`, `phoneNumber`, etc. So the `profile` does not have any `gov_agency` property.

You are apparently mixing up the values you can get from `firebase.auth` with the ones that you have saved in the real time database.

You should therefore query the database, based on the `userId` or on the `email` (depends on your data model), in order to get the values of `gov_agency` (and `displayName`) to "determine if it is a gov client or a citizen client".

To query the database, refer to https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write and https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data

Note that `displayName` IS also property of `UserInfo`, but apparently you have not set it when creating the users.

Answer (score 0):

Note from the doc:

> currentUser might also be null because the auth object has not
>   finished initializing...

Try:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    console.log('User is signed in:', user);
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
    console.log('No user is signed in', user);
  }
});
```

CMIIW